# Formatting curl to clone git repos using clone_url and user:token

Tags: git, curl, https, clone

I currently have a shell script that I want to use as part of a Jenkins/Docker job that clones all of the repos from my organization that are tagged with a specific language.

```
curl -s -H "Authorization: token "$token"" https://github.[company].com/api/v3/orgs/$org/repos\?page\=$i\&per_page\=100 |
jq '.[] | select(.language != null) | select(.language | contains("'$lang'")).ssh_url' | xargs -n 1 git clone
```

For most instances it works but I realized that I need to have SSH configured in the Docker container for it to work properly. Rather than dealing with trying to get that set up, I found I can still clone using HTTPS with a user:token combo.

`git clone https://user:token@github.[company].com/organization/repo.git`

My issue is that I am getting a list of all of the target repos and cloning them, so I need to pass the user:token somehow for each one. I know I can get the clone_url instead of the ssh_url but I do not know how to insert the credentials. I have looked around a lot but have not found anything that is helping me with this issue. Does anyone know if and how I can format the script so it passes the credentials in the URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose I was looking at the wrong part of the script for the formatting. I ended up using sed on the curl/jq output to format the url before using xargs to git clone.

```
sed 's,https://,https://user:token@,g'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow "[Dockerizing Jenkins: Securing Passwords With docker-compose, docker-secret and Jenkins Credentials Plugin](https://dzone.com/articles/securing-password-with-docker-compose-docker-secre)" from  Kayan Azimov

It uses a secret to register the password

```
secrets:
  artifactoryPassword:
    file: ./secrets/artifactoryPassword
```

> It will bind mount docker secret files, to which we can later refer from container by `/run/secrets/secret_name_here` path.

If not, you can also add to your script

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/github.[company].com".insteadOf "git@github.com/github.[company].com"
```

No more `sed` to do.
See [`git config url.<base>.insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf).

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion but it wasn't quite what I was looking for in this particular case. I actually figured it out. I will definitely keep this in mind as I start using Docker more.

Comment: @jb11 I have added an alternative which avoids any sed.